# Manage Tags on store bases Magento

Tags: magento

I have multiple stores in magento. I want to manage Tags on store bases.  I add Tags from magento admin and change status to approved but not showing on frontend store.
My question is how to assign magento tags to particular store.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

[image]

You can assign to perticular stores like this. It will show only when you have multiple stores.

Remove your cache and try.

Refer this link : http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/tags